# How to create .d.ts file with multiple, possibly conflicting requirements

Tags: javascript, typescript

Because [`tsd`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) is deprecated, I'm trying to migrate an ambient declaration file on [`DefinitelyTyped`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) to the structure [`typings`](https://github.com/typings/typings) encourages (external modules). Here's the [typings repo](https://github.com/OlsonDev/typed-keyboardjs) I'm making for KeyboardJS and [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/OlsonDev/typed-keyboardjs/issues/1) that lead to this question.

KeyboardJS is pretty simple (3 classes, 2 interfaces, 1 instance) but creating a proper `.d.ts` file for it has been troublesome for me. My requirements are simple:

1. No ambient/global declarations
2. Be able to extend exported members
3. Be able to access type info from non-JS-exported members

The problem comes in with how KeyboardJS does its exports:

```js
var Keyboard = require('./lib/keyboard');
var Locale   = require('./lib/locale');
var KeyCombo = require('./lib/key-combo');

var keyboard = new Keyboard();

keyboard.setLocale('us', require('./locales/us'));

exports          = module.exports = keyboard;
exports.Keyboard = Keyboard;
exports.Locale   = Locale;
exports.KeyCombo = KeyCombo;
```

There are two other interfaces KeyboardJS has (*but does not expose*), `KeyEvent` and `EventHandler`:

```ts
interface KeyEvent extends KeyboardEvent {
    preventRepeat(): void;
    pressedKeys: string;
}

interface EventHandler {
    (e?: KeyEvent): void;
}
```

So, the `.d.ts` file needs to expose `Keyboard`, `Locale`, & `KeyCombo` classes as well as `default` (as an instance of `Keyboard`) -- as an [external module](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/external-modules.md). I should be able to write TypeScript classes that extend the JavaScript classes. Also, I need to be able write functions having `KeyEvent` and `EventHandler` as parameters.

Is this possible with the current state of TypeScript or do I need to file a TypeScript bug to support this scenario? If it's possible, how would I go about writing the `.d.ts` file?

Comment: At 14k I wonder if porting to typescript would be an easier way to get the definitions you're looking for?

Comment: @CoreyAlix I've considered it but I have to imagine other libraries have similar shapes. While my question is specific, I'm interested in the answer more generically as external module type declarations become more prolific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created test.ts to hopefully simulate your library:

```
export class Keyboard {
    hereiam() { }
}

export class Locale { }

export class KeyCombo { }

let out = new Keyboard();
export default out;
```

And the resulting d.ts:

```
export declare class Keyboard {
    hereiam(): void;
}
export declare class Locale {
}
export declare class KeyCombo {
}
declare let out: Keyboard;
export default out;
```

And finally the way I was able to consume it:

```
import {default as l} from "./test";
l.hereiam();
```

So taking the definition a little further you can add the two interfaces:

```
declare module "lib" {

    export interface KeyEvent extends KeyboardEvent {
        preventRepeat(): void;
        pressedKeys: string;
    }

    export interface EventHandler {
        (e?: KeyEvent): void;
    }

    export class Keyboard {
        hereiam(): void;
    }
    export class Locale {
    }
    export class KeyCombo {
    }

    let out: Keyboard;
    export default out;
}
```

And then consume them like this:

```
import * as lib from "lib";
let l = lib.default;
l.hereiam();
let k = new lib.Keyboard();
k.hereiam();

var x: lib.EventHandler;
var y: lib.KeyEvent;
y.preventRepeat;
```

Comment: That's a similar approach to what blakeembrey mentioned in the linked GitHub issue and has the same downside: How do you write a function that requires a `KeyEvent` or `EventHandler` when the library doesn't export them?

Comment: Can't you add them to the definition (see edited answer)?

Comment: Thanks, I gave you a +1 because that does indeed fix the main concern. The only remaining issue is both of these are valid from TypeScript: `const k1 = new lib.Keyboard();` & `const k2 = new lib.default.Keyboard();` but the former will throw a runtime error. I wonder if it's possible to hide `lib.default.Keyboard` **scratches head**

Comment: Turns out the type union/intersection is unnecessary; you could just do `const out: Keyboard; export default out;` Change your answer to reflect that and I'll accept it. :-)

Comment: @Olson.dev I'm not trying to write your actual interface, just figure out how you can write it :)  Anyway I removed the mixin since I guess that wasn't a proper representation of your library.  I hope you decide to port it to typescript; it's an enjoyable development experience.